# pyqt memory leak with stylesheet

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

pyqt4 |   qt 4.8  |  linux (open suse) | python 2.7

I have a simple question about a strange behaviour concerning pyqt and python memory.

I did a little test, a widget, the creation of 1000 buttons on this widget and set the parent to the widget to None.

I think that the good behaviour is, on the widget (with 1000 buttons inside) if we do widget.setParent(None), qt will destroy it (and all of his children).

but if we add a widget.setStyleSheet('background-color:green'), it seems to be that qt doesn't destroy button, OR python doesn't free the memory of these buttons.

a simple test code. (good behaviour)

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        widgetCentral = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        for dummy in range(1000):
            beginBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(widgetCentral)
            beginBtn.setText('btn')

        # without this line, the memory is 22mo, if we had this line, the memory fall to 15mo
        #widgetCentral.setParent(None) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and now, the same example with the style sheet

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        widgetCentral = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        widgetCentral.setStyleSheet('background-color:green;')
        for dummy in range(1000):
            beginBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(widgetCentral)
            beginBtn.setText('btn')

        # with or without this line, the memory is 22mo/23mo
        #widgetCentral.setParent(None) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

so it seems to be a bad behaviour with style sheet and python memory (garbage ?)

someone has an idea about this behaviour ? 
it's a bug or just a bad implementation ?

Comment: Python can try to return memory to the system, but there's no guarantee that the OS will be able to release it (because of fragmentation). Have you tried testing with a more recent version python? I think python3 may handle this better than python2.

Comment: I can't reproduce on windows 8.1, Python 2.7 (32-bit), PyQt4 v4.11.2 (binary installer). Uncommenting `widgetCentral.setParent(None)` in the second example seems to release memory correctly. Only thing I noticed was that my memory usage was much smaller than yours for all examples (so I increased the number of buttons to 10,000 so that the memory usage was more obvious)